# Javascript data bind element attribute to anchor href in URL

Tags: javascript, data-binding

How could I go about binding `location.hash` to an HTML element attribute? For example, the following element

```
<span id="mySpan" data-foo=""></span>
```

changes to

```
<span id="mySpan" data-foo="bar"></span>
```

when the URL changes to `/index.html#bar`. Then it changes to

```
<span id="mySpan" data-foo="buzz"></span>
```

when the URL changes to `/index.html#buzz`.

jQuery is *acceptable*, but I'd rather do this in plain JS. Any ideas?

Comment: You would bind the change to the setting of the value. Create a function or structure to manage the data attribute and inside of the management change the hash.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `window.onhashchange`, like this

```
window.onhashchange = function(){

    document.getElementById("mySpan").setAttribute("data-foo",location.hash.slice(1)); 

};
```